# Mongoose '.inlcudes' - Argument of type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ type: ObjectId; required: true; }'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I'm in the process of converting my JS node/express & mongoose server over to Typescript, and I have an issue with mongoose's array includes method with typescript:

```
Argument of type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ type: ObjectId; required: true; }'.
  Type 'ObjectId' is missing the following properties from type '{ type: ObjectId; required: true; }': type, required

78     if (!building.actors.includes(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID)))
```

The line causing this issue is below:

```
const transformedUserID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userID)
if (transformedUserID && !building.actors.includes(transformedUserID)) {
   ...
```

The error says that the required property is missing, so I thought maybe it was an issue involving userID possibly being null, so I tried this with no success:

```
transformedUserID || mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
```

I'm new to Typescript so am not really sure why this is happening, it worked perfectly fine in plain JS. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Worked out what the issue was - I was using `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` in my typescript interface for the Buildings model, instead of `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`.